# PowerPivot transpose column headers on rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have two datasources, one comes from an excel file i cannot change with this format

```
item | week 1 | week 2 | ...
ITM01|   12   |    23  | ...
```

My second datasource comes from a query and looks like

```
item | Week | Value
ITM01|  1   |   5
ITM02|  2   |   10
...
```

I need to merge the two tables to have, hopefully, something like

```
item | Week | Value 1 | Value 2
ITM01|  1   |   5     |   12
ITM01|  2   |   10    |   23
...
```

I'd like to achieve this in powerpivot, considering that I cannot change the excel datasource, and i would like it to be updateable by using excels refresh button, which means, i think, that i should not create custom tables to handle the transposition, as that might ruin the refresh.

I'm really lost on how to achieve this and some help would be much appreciated.

I'd also add that i can change the second data source to look like the first one(weeks on columns), but while i might be able to connect the two tables, i would still not know how to achieve the desired output with weeks on rows.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Are you able to use Power Query to help you?  It has a feature called [unpivot](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/unpivot-columns-HA104053356.aspx) that does exactly what you want. Power Query download is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379).

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion, I am using excel 2013 and Power Query did exactly what i needed to do and helped somewhere else too. Cheers.